# How can I add language selection to the user profile in "my account" settings

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n, users

I'm currently allowing users to switch language with the "Language switcher" block, but I would like have this as part of the user profile that is managed with the "My Account" settings page.

Is it possible to add this as a field? Adding a field is no problem, but can I make it refer to the language setting that is normally controlled by the language switcher block? I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: Never mind, I completely overlooked it! Language settings is already present in the account settings page

Comment: Whiskey, if you solved your problem, please post the solution (discovery) as an answer to the question so it can be marked as accepted, or you may otherwise close the question

Comment: I will, but was not allowed to answer so soon after I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language setting is already present in the account settings page, I was misguided by the first part of the description "This account's default language for e-mails, ..." and skipped over the rest that read "... and preferred language for site presentation." doh!